# Is there any way to solve this error when compiling in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio-3.0

[My Android studio gives me error. The build error whenever I try to run any project. Please help how to solve it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tehrj.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post images of error messages when you can instead just copy the text out!

Answer (score 0):

It seems Gradle is in offline mode and thus can't download required resources. [This page](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build#offline_mode) explains how to *turn on* offline mode, I'm pretty sure you can figure out the inverse from there.

Comment: You're welcome. For future reference, there's no need to post "thank you" comments, a simple upvote is thanks enough if you found an answer useful.